# How to make a mask in Editable YII2?

Tags: php, web, yii2

I have such code. It is important that there is a mask when editing a field:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'another_number',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => \kartik\editable\Editable::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'another_number',
        'asPopover' => false,
        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
        'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'editable'],
        'inlineSettings' => [
            'closeButton' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger kv-editable-close" title="Закрыть">
                    <i class="fas fa-xmark"></i>
                </button>',
        ],
    ])
],
```

I need this mask: `+7 (999) 999-99-99`

Yii2

Input:
`'mask' => '+7 (999) 999-99-99'`

Output:
`Nothing`

---

Input:
`'data-inputmask' => '+7 (999) 999-99-99'`

Output:
`Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use this widget?
I found another one, [Yii 2.0 Masked Input widget](https://demos.krajee.com/masked-input).
It helps you?

Comment: No :(

I need to make it so that the field can only be edited if you click on it. Directly in view

Comment: Actually,  in comment section of Kartik's Editable documentation there is an example how to combine editable widget with masked input widget. Look for wierus' question and Yusuf Ayuba's answer.